# date time picker crashing when generating a new row

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, datetimepicker

I am trying to implement a dateTimePicker in generated rows but it's crashing in the first row and it's not working in the generated rows

this is the jQuery code for the generated rows the DateTimePicker is not working in the generated rows

```js
$(function() {
  $(document).on("click", '.btn-add-row', function() {
    var id = $(this).closest("table.table-review").attr('id'); // Id of particular table
    console.log(id);
    var div = $("<tr />");
    div.html(GetDynamicTextBox(id));
    $("#" + id + "_tbody").append(div);
    $(".prodName3").select2();
    $(".varName3").select2();
  });
  $(document).on("click", "#comments_remove", function() {
    $(this).closest("tr").prev().find('td:last-child').html('<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" id="comments_remove"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i></button>');
    $(this).closest("tr").remove();

  });

  function GetDynamicTextBox(table_id) {
    //$('#comments_remove').remove();
    var rowsLength = document.getElementById(table_id).getElementsByTagName("tbody")[0].getElementsByTagName("tr").length + 1;
    return '<td>' + rowsLength + '</td>' +
      '<td><select  name = "DynamicTextBox" class="select form-control prodName3" value = "" style="width:289.3px;"><option>Select</option><option>ProdDolar</option><option>ProdLBP</option><option>Souna</option></select></td>' +
      '<td><select  name = "DynamicTextBox" class="select form-control varName3" value = "" style="width:289.3px;"><option>Select</option><option>ProdLBPmmm1B3</option></select></td>' +
      '<td><input type="text" name = "DynamicTextBox" class="form-control" value = "mm" readonly></td>' +
      '<td><div class="cal-icon"><input class="form-control floating datetimepicker" name = "DynamicTextBox" type="text"></td>' +
      '<td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="DynamicTextBox" onkeyup = "javascript:this.value=Comma(this.value);" ></td>' +
      '<td><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" id="comments_remove"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i></button></td>'


  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.13/js/select2.min.js" ></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.13/css/select2.min.css"  />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.37/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css" integrity="sha512-WWc9iSr5tHo+AliwUnAQN1RfGK9AnpiOFbmboA0A0VJeooe69YR2rLgHw13KxF1bOSLmke+SNnLWxmZd8RTESQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.3/moment.min.js" integrity="sha512-x/vqovXY/Q4b+rNjgiheBsA/vbWA3IVvsS8lkQSX1gQ4ggSJx38oI2vREZXpTzhAv6tNUaX81E7QBBzkpDQayA==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.37/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js" integrity="sha512-Y+0b10RbVUTf3Mi0EgJue0FoheNzentTMMIE2OreNbqnUPNbQj8zmjK3fs5D2WhQeGWIem2G2UkKjAL/bJ/UXQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>


<div class="hidden" id="tableshow">
  <section class="review-section">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="table-responsive">
          <table class="table table-review review-table mb-0" id="table_achievements">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th style="width:40px;">#</th>
                <th>Product Name</th>
                <th>Variant Name</th>
                <th>Base Unit</th>
                <th>Effective Date</th>
                <th>Purchase Price</th>
                <th style="width: 64px;"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-add-row"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></button></th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody id="table_achievements_tbody">
              <tr>
                <th>1</th>
                <th>
                  <select class="form-control select" id="prodName" style="width:289.3px;">
                    <option>Select</option>
                    <option>ProdDolar</option>
                    <option>ProdLBP</option>
                    <option>Souna</option>
                  </select>
                </th>
                <th>
                  <select class="form-control" id="varName" style="width:289.3px;">
                    <option>Select</option>
                    <option>ProdLBPmmm1B3</option>
                  </select>
                </th>
                <th><input type="text" class="form-control" value="mm" readonly></th>
                <th>
                  <div class="cal-icon"><input class="form-control floating datetimepicker" type="text"></th>
                <!-- <input type="number" class="form-control" > -->
                <th><input type="text" class="form-control" name="Price" onkeyup="javascript:this.value=Comma(this.value);"></th>
                <th></th>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
  </section>
  </div>
```

added the library sdfsdfsdfsdf sdfsd fsd fsd fs dfs df sdf fds sfd f
sd fsd fs
d fsd
fs

Comment: I made you a snippet. The backslashes in this line is not valid JS `var rowsLength = document.getElementById(table_id).getElementsByTagName("tbody")\[0\].getElementsByTagName("tr").length + 1;` so I removed them

Comment: You need to run select2 on the static row too: `$("#prodName").select2();
  $("#varName").select2();`

Comment: Also `datetimepicker`? where is the code for that?

Comment: yeah i runed the select 2 on the static row but i didn't put it in the question because it;s working i only need the date time picker field
i tried removing the element beween the backslases now it;s not generating rows ...for the dateTimePicker , for the dateTimePicker  it's a plugin you import the css and js

Comment: So please add the missing code

Comment: i added the libraries but theirs an error in the snipset ...but i added the moment.js still not catching it